# Weird characters outputting in server side

Tags: c, sockets

I have a bunch of weird characters in my output file when I send it from the client to the server. When I stream the server into an array and print it out, it looks good and legible. However, when I send it over to the server, I get a bunch of weird characters and MICROSOFT everywhere in the text document. Anybody know what's wrong?

Client:

```
if(sendSize <=0){
    for(;;){
        unsignedchar buff[256]={0};
        int nread = fread(buff,1,256, fp);

        total = total + nread;
        percentage =(total / fFileSize)*100;
        printf("\r%s: Percentage sent: %.2f", NAME_C, percentage);
        /* Send data in 256 byte chunks */
        if(nread >0){
            send(clientSock, buff, nread, 0);
        }

        if(nread <256){
            if(feof(fp)){
                printf("\nSend Success!\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //printf("%.2f", total);
}
```

Server:

```
/* Receive data from client */
    char* fileName ="test.txt";
    FILE*fp = fopen(fileName,"w+");;

    float total =0;
    float bytesReceived;
    unsignedchar buff[256]={0};
    float percentage =(bytesReceived / total)*100;

    while((bytesReceived = recv(listenSock, buff,sizeof(buff),0))<0){
        //bytesReceived = recv(listenSock, buff, 256, 0);
        if(bytesReceived >0){
            printf("DONE");
        }
        //total = total + bytesReceived;
        fwrite(buff,sizeof(char), bytesReceived, fp);
        //printf("\r%s: Percentage received: %.2f", NAME_C, percentage);
    }
```

Comment: What is `unsignedchar`?

Comment: What operating system are you using on the two systems? If either of them is Windows, you should use binary mode when opening the file if it's not a text file.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: The `b` mode: `fopen(filename, "wb+")`

Comment: Why are you calling `recv` on the listening socket? Shouldn't you be trying to receive data from the socket that's connected to the client?

Answer (score 0):

Your server's `recv()` loop is using `<0` when it should be using `>0` instead. `recv()` returns -1 on error, 0 on graceful disconnect, and >0 on bytes received.

Also, is `listenSock` the actual listening socket, or the socket returned by `accept()`?  You should be passing the latter to `recv()`.  My guess is that you are passing the former instead, causing `recv()` to fail and return -1, which you then enter the body of the loop with garbage `buff` data and a bad `bytesReceived` value.  The third parameter of `fwrite()` is a `size_t`, which is an *unsigned* type, so passing a *signed* value of -1 will get interpreted as an *unsigned* value of `4294967295` or even `18446744073709551615`, depending on the size of `size_t`.  Either way, you would be writing garbage to your file, or even crashing the code trying to access invalid memory.

There are other minor issues with your code as well.  Try something more like this instead:

Client:

```
if(sendSize <=0){
    unsigned char buff[256];
    do{
        int nread = fread(buff, sizeof(char), 256, fp);
        if (nread > 0){
            total += nread;
            percentage = (total / fFileSize)*100;
            printf("\r%s: Percentage sent: %.2f", NAME_C, percentage);
            /* Send data in 256 byte chunks */
            if (send(clientSock, buff, nread, 0) == -1){
                printf("\nSend Failed!\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        if (nread != 256){
            if (feof(fp)){
                printf("\nSend Success!\n");
            else
                printf("\nRead Failed!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    while (1);
    //printf("%.2f", total);
}
```

Server:

```
/* Receive data from client */
char* fileName = "test.txt";
FILE* fp = fopen(fileName, "wb+");
if (!fp){
    printf("\nOpen Failed!\n");
}
else{
    float total = 0;
    float percentage = 0;
    int bytesReceived;
    unsigned char buff[256];

    do{
        bytesReceived = recv(acceptedSock, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
        if (bytesReceived <= 0){
            if (bytesReceived < 0){
                printf("\nRecv Failed!\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("\nDisconnected!\n");
            }
            break;
        }
        //total += bytesReceived;
        //percentage = ...
        if (fwrite(buff, sizeof(char), bytesReceived, fp) != bytesReceived){
            printf("\nWrite Failed!\n");
            break;
        }
        //printf("\n%s: Percentage received: %.2f", NAME_C, percentage);
    }
    while (1);
}
```